# Apps Script how to customize sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script, spreadsheet

I want to write a function that creates several sheets with the same design, it is a specific template that has been created manually, the question is, can this sheet be used to create new ones that look like it (without copying&pasting the sheet preferably), or do I have to code every single customization like cell background color, font, etc. and than generate the sheets?

I could write the code manually, I was just wandering if there is a way to use/import an existing sheet's appearance properties.